# How to convert netTcpBinding to customBinding?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, nettcpbinding

I am trying to convert **netTcpBinding** to **customBinding**.

Here is **netTcpBinding** configuration:

```
<netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="DuplexBinding" sendTimeout="00:00:30" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      <reliableSession enabled="true" ordered="true"/>
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>                    
    </binding>
</netTcpBinding>
```

I have created a **CustomDuplexBinding**:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="CustomDuplexBinding" sendTimeout="00:00:30">
      <transactionFlow />
      <reliableSession ordered="true"/>
      <security authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate" enableUnsecuredResponse="true">
        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameForCertificate" />
      </security>
      <compositeDuplex />
      <oneWay />
      <binaryMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                      maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
      </binaryMessageEncoding>
      <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="false"/>
      <tcpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

But when I run, following exception has occured:

> Binding 'CustomDuplexBinding' doesn't support creating any channel types.
>   This often indicates that the BindingElements in a CustomBinding have
>   been stacked incorrectly or in the wrong order. A Transport is
>   required at the bottom of the stack. The recommended order for
>   BindingElements is: TransactionFlow, ReliableSession, Security,
>   CompositeDuplex, OneWay, StreamSecurity, MessageEncoding, Transport.

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: Did you try switching the order of `<sslStreamSecurity>` and `<tcpTransport>`?

Comment: I have tried to switch the order and got the exception: "_In Binding 'CustomBinding', TransportBindingElement 'TcpTransportBindingElement' does not appear last in the BindingElementCollection.  Please change the order of elements such that the TransportBindingElement is last_."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message:  "...StreamSecurity, MessageEncoding..."

In your binding congifuration, you have `<<binaryMessageEncoding>` followed by `<sslStreamSecurity>`.  These need to be switched:

```
<sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="false"/>
<binaryMessageEncoding>
  <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
</binaryMessageEncoding>
```

Per [Custom Bindings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347793%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN, the following is the **required order**:

- Transaction Flow
- Reliable Session
- Security
- Composite Duplex
- OneWay
- Stream Security
- Message Encoding
- Transport

Only the last two (Message Encoding and Transport) are required; the rest are optional.

Comment: I've tried a few combinations but got no results. The required order didn't work as well. I've removed security element and service started successfully. I don't know what wrong with security. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Tim after two weeks I see your post and your bold text : **required order** saved my life for my wsHttp custom binding! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this same problem.  Although the Stream Security and Message Encoding elements were backwards in the original post, the same error occurs even when they are in the correct order.  For me, the issue was with the authenticationMode being used on the security element.  My nettcp security element was the same as the original poster's (Message security with UserName authentication).  Using this worked:

```
<security authenticationMode="SecureConversation">
   <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="UserNameForSslNegotiated" />
</security>
```